# Firefox selenium automation using gecko driver is throwing error as too many open files after 400 +cases ran

Tags: python, selenium, geckodriver, python-unittest

when I run FF using geckodriver after around 400 cases run - it starts throwing an error as

> " Error: [('C:\file_name\..\FFAutomation\addons.json',
>   'c:\users\ucep-q~1\appdata\local\temp\2\tmpnvxvkk\webdriver-py-profilecopy\addons.json',"[Errno
>   24] Too many open files:"

I have tried using batch file which will delete the cache as well as temp files in a period of 1 hour,still I get such issue.
I see the log file is also very large.

If any one can suggest what can be the issue.

- Language : Python
- Framework : pyunit
- Selenium webdriver 3.4.1
- Geckodriver: v0.19.0

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with selenium???

Comment: I m trying to run a regression suite having 1700 cases.If I run a single case it runs but when I run the entire suite,it gives an error as too many open files after 400 + cases is passed.And the regression stops with a result emailed .

Comment: Strange but nice question

Comment: If each case will start a new browser, please quite the browser at the end of case.

Comment: We have tried this and still face the same issues.